# Status of photon velocity in perturbative calculation of QED in curved spacetime

Tags: photons, perturbation-theory, cosmic-microwave-background, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.22.343) by Drummond et. al. by doing perturbative calculation of photon propagator in a curved spacetime they found that in certain directions in a given spacetime quantum correction suggests the speed of photon goes beyond $c$. For example:

1. In Schwarzschild metric this change in speed leads to a change in deflection of light given $$\delta\phi=-\frac{\alpha}{45\pi}\left(\frac{\lambda_c}{r_0}\right)^2\left(\frac{4GM}{r_0}\right),$$ where $\lambda_c$ is electron comptons wavelength and $r_0$ is minimum value of r on  photons trajectory/orbit. For our solar system this gives $\delta\phi\approx3\times10^{-47}\Delta\phi$, where $\Delta\phi$ is the normal deflection of light by Sun (arround $1.75$ arc sec).
2. For the FLRW metric in the radiation-dominated regime the speed comes out to be $1+\frac{11\xi^2}{4t^2}$ where $\xi^2=\frac{\alpha}{90\pi m_e^2}$. The factor of $t$ in the denominator clearly indicates the breakdown of perturbation but in the conclusion section, the authors refer to a comment by Gibbons that this correction may have some implication on the isotropy of CMBR.

I tried to look for any progress on this result using [connected papers](https://www.connectedpapers.com/main/9f81ea4859d16e874e25b11a953256401eb2a2dc/QED-Vacuum-Polarization-in-a-Background-Gravitational-Field-and-Its-Effect-on-the-Velocity-of-Photons/graph) but so far I could not see any conclusive progress to make sense of this result.